# Background Images in HTML Email look blurry on mobile devices

Tags: email, html-email

Background images in HTML email look blurry when viewed on mobile phone.

There is a technique for swapping out a wider banner image for a smaller background image on mobile devices. Email on Acid has a [nice write-up](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/a_slick_new_image_swapping_technique_for_responsive_emails/)  that explains using a media query to hide the `img` and add a background-image to it's parent `td`.  Pretty simple.

**However, my issue is the background image looks blurry on iPhone and Androids in my Litmus tests and actual device testing.**

Has anyone else come across this issue? I optimized the jpg to look good (85 quality setting in photoshop's save for web feature). It looks good on my computer.

I also did an interesting test where I viewed the html for the email on my iPhone4 using mobile safari and the background image was not blurry. Whereas when I use mailchimp to send the email it looks blurry on my phone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the Android / iPhone scaling the background images to match it's pixel density. You should be able to make your background image twice as big and put a style of `background-size:100px 100px;` or whatever the original dimensions were on the `td`.